# Cannot apply unary operator `!` with Diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using `!` to do a not equal like this:

```
    ChannelRequest { excludeEditorPickChannel, ..} if excludeEditorPickChannel.unwrap_or(0) == 1 => Box::new(!editor_pick.eq(excludeEditorPickChannel)),
```

When I compile this code it shows an error:

```
error[E0600]: cannot apply unary operator `!` to type `diesel::expression::operators::Eq<dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::columns::editor_pick, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, &std::option::Option<i32>>>`
  --> src/service/app/cruise/channel/channel_service.rs:35:114
   |
35 | ...unwrap_or(0) == 1 => Box::new(!editor_pick.eq(excludeEditorPickChannel)),
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot apply unary operator `!`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0600`.
warning: `reddwarf-admin` (bin "reddwarf-admin") generated 10 warnings
error: could not compile `reddwarf-admin` due to previous error; 10 warnings emitted
```

`editor_pick` was the diesel table schema column. The table is defined like this:

```
table! {
    rss_sub_source (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        sub_url -> Varchar,
        created_time -> Int8,
        updated_time -> Int8,
        sub_status -> Int2,
        rss_type -> Varchar,
        standard_type -> Varchar,
        standard_version -> Varchar,
        cron -> Varchar,
        trigger_count -> Int4,
        next_trigger_time -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        sub_name -> Varchar,
        last_trigger_time -> Nullable<Timestamptz>,
        tags -> Nullable<Array<Int4>>,
        source_url -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        sub_type -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        intro -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        remark -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        title_hash -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        failed_count -> Int4,
        lang -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        frequency_month -> Nullable<Int4>,
        reputation -> Nullable<Int4>,
        rep_lastest_refresh_time -> Nullable<Int8>,
        scrapy_take_time -> Nullable<Int4>,
        follower -> Nullable<Int8>,
        censor_status -> Nullable<Int4>,
        etag -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        last_modified -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        editor_pick -> Nullable<Int4>,
        fav_icon_url -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        dynamic_interval -> Int4,
        local_icon_url -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        creator -> Int8,
    }
}
```

`excludeEditorPickChannel` was the parameter which received by the rust rocket, the `excludeEditorPickChannel` define like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct ChannelRequest {
    pub userId: Option<i64>,
    pub pageNum: Option<i64>,
    pub pageSize: Option<i64>,
    pub editorPick: Option<i32>,
    pub minimalReputation: Option<i32>,
    pub excludeEditorPickChannel: Option<i32>
}
```

Why can't I apply the `!`? What should I do to implement the not equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ne`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/expression_methods/trait.ExpressionMethods.html#method.ne) instead of `!eq`.